# UIlabel text getting shifted down

Tags: ios, uilabel, ios9, xcode7

I am having multiple `UILabel` in a table view cell but `UILabel` with dynamic width is showing weird kind of behaviour in iOS8/7 when running from xcode7.
When I am running my code in iOS 9(iPad) `UILabel` working fine.
[image]

But when I am running it in iOS 8 or 7 text is shifted down.

in iOS 8 (iPad)
[image]

in iOS 7 (iPhone 4)
[image]

**Note:** Green background color showing background color of UILabel frame.
Font is same in all three.

**I wanted to know why this is happening and whats the solution for this behaviour?**

Edit:

Constraint for label "One" with green background color.

[image]

Constraint for label "One" with no background color.

**Note: Width of this label is dynamic and on basis of which trailing space of label "One" with green background color is adjusted.**

[image]

Edit 2:
Constraint for "DATE" label.

[image]

**Edit3: 
I resolved it self, i fixed the no of lines for label to 1. Then it worked but still i am not able to find out why this only happened in iOS8/7 not in iOS9?**

Comment: Can you share your labels constraints?

Comment: Added screenshot of constraint @VitaliyGozhenko

Comment: I don't see constraints for the date label at the bottom. Can you share it?

Comment: Added that also. @VitaliyGozhenko

Answer (score 0):

It seems your label is compressed. If you are using AutoLayout, try to give your compressed label's vertical compression resistance priority a larger value or make your cell's height a litter larger

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't pin your bottom label (date label) to bottom of the cell...

You need add constraint for date label: bottom spacing between date label and superview

[image]

Comment: Please check edited answer it is resolved but i am still not sure about the reason and i also tried this thing but it didn't worked @vitaliy

Comment: @AkshaySunderwani did you sure, that you set correct `preferredLabelWidth` for your labels? It can happens because of it